# How to use git-filter-repo to merge one repo as subdirectory into another

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

While trying to use `git filter-branch` to merge repos using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/icholy/6491787bbb6894dbf4fe69a743975332). Adding just the relevant snippet in question:

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter '
        mkdir -p "${REPO_NAME}_tmp"
        git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT | xargs -I{} mv {} "${REPO_NAME}_tmp"
        mv "${REPO_NAME}_tmp" "$REPO_NAME"
    '
```

I got a warning from git stating the following:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
```

So, I took a look at `git filter-repo`, the [description](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#DESCRIPTION) states the following:

> restructuring the file layout (such as moving all files into a subdirectory in preparation for merging with another repo, ...

This showed that this issue can be resolved with `git filter-repo`, but even after checking the documentation and given [examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) I could not find a way to achieve this. Can someone please help me with the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the `filter-branch` command in the script

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter '
        mkdir -p "${REPO_NAME}_tmp"
        git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT | xargs -I{} mv {} "${REPO_NAME}_tmp"
        mv "${REPO_NAME}_tmp" "$REPO_NAME"
    '
```

with this

```
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter "$REPO_NAME"
```

See **Path shortcuts** section [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#OPTIONS)

> --to-subdirectory-filter `<directory>`
>
> Treat the project root as instead being under `<directory>`
>
> Equivalent to using `--path-rename :<directory>/`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a path-rename, as part of the [path-based filters](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd  $REPO_DIR_TMP
git filter-repo  --path-rename /:${REPO_NAME}_tmp/
```

That would rewrite the history of the second repo in a subfolder (within that second repo)

Then you can add it as a remote of the first repo, fetch and merge, as in your gitst.

Comment: This returns : `Error: With --path-rename, if OLD_NAME and NEW_NAME are both non-empty and either ends with a slash then both must.`

Comment: Add a slash to the folder